# How to change saturation and value using slider qcolor?

Tags: c++, qt, qcolor

Can someone help me make two sliders named brightness and saturation for changing both brightness and saturation, I set up a dialog with QLabel for displaying image and two sliders below. I tried converting my image to HSV then change S and V. But that does not work.

```
void Dialog::sliderchange(QLabel *label,int value){
QImage image=label->pixmap()->toImage();
for(int i=0;i<image.width();i++){
    for(int j=0;j<image.height();j++){
        QColor color=image.pixelColor(i,j);
        color.convertTo(QColor::Hsv);
        value=color.value();
        color.setHsv(color.hue(),color.saturation(),value);

    }
}
}

void Dialog::on_brightness_valueChanged(int value){
  sliderchange(ui->label,value);
}
```

Comment: add `image.setPixelColor(i, j, color)` after `color.setHsv(color.hue(),color.saturation(),value);` and add `label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image))` after the last line of the function `sliderchange`

Comment: I just coded, the slider seems laggy when sliding but the image did not change.

Comment: You have a local variable `value` which *hides* your parameter. So, the color remains unchanged. Add a call to `QApplication::processEvents`and your slider would be more fluent.